# "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" after using remove() on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code:

```
list_of_directions = ['right', 'left', 'up', 'down']
new_list = list_of_directions.remove('right')

print(len(new_list))
```

But I get the error message

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I thought I understood how `.remove()` works, but maybe I don't?

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.remove` is an *in-place* operation. It returns `None`.

You need to perform this operation in a separate line to `new_list`. In other words, instead of `new_list = list_of_directions.remove('right')`:

```
new_list = list_of_directions[:]

new_list.remove('right')
```

In the above logic, we assign `new_list` to a copy of `list_of_directions` before removing a specific element.

Notice the importance of assigning to a **copy** of `list_of_directions`. This is to avoid the highly probable scenario of `new_list` changing with `list_of_directions` in an undesired manner.

The behaviour you are seeing is noted explicitly in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> You might have noticed that methods like `insert`, `remove` or `sort`
>   that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return
>   the default `None`. This is a design principle for all mutable data
>   structures in Python.

Comment: Note: If the goal is to preserve the original `list_of_directions`, you'd want to reverse the operations; make `new_list = list_of_directions[:]`, *then* call `new_list.remove('right')`. Otherwise, the two lists end up with the same contents, which is fairly pointless. Alternatively, combine the two operations into a list comprehension: `new_list = [d for d in list_of_directions if d != 'right']` (differs behaviorally, since it will remove multiple instances of `'right'` if they exist, but probably what is desired in this case).